# "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory" only when compiling with debug flag

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, out-of-memory, stdmap

I get the error with following code (error.cpp):

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::map<
        int, std::map< std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
        std::map<std::string, std::string>
            > > >
            > > >
            > > >
            > > >
            > > >
            > > >
            > >                                         oups;

}
```

When compiling with debug flag:

```
g++ error.cpp -g -o error
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 with g++ 7.5.0 running as a VM.
RAM is 5GB and Swap is 2.5GB. Hard disk space left 1GB.

Is this normal? A bug? A limitation?

What would be a "nicer" alternative for above code ? (c++14)

Comment: What would be "nicer", probably something less ridiculous?

Comment: I would really not use a data structure like this.  You might be better of making a DB and querying that.  Really depends on what this is supposed to represent.

Comment: Good news! Visual Studio agrees... `fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space`

Comment: Could you guess - how many maps you have declared?

Comment: What’s special about 18 levels of nesting? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Interesting, usage aside, can anyone provide an actual answer to the author's question about what and why is it happening? I mean, 20 levels of nested templates is not that much, is there some branching leading to exponentials?

Comment: @Sneftel: this allows me to have store/search as a hash, e.g.: oups["blah"]["bla"]["blah2"]...["blah"], then search oups.at("blah")...at("blah2"). The 18 levels is what my application needs. Why to use a database if I can use native c++?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to have a map with a struct of strings as a key.

Comment: @Sneftel thanks that should work for me.

Comment: The standard does include (non-normative) recommendations on minimum limits for template nesting.  That limit was 17 in older standards compared with your 18 or more, I'm not sure about more recent standards.

Comment: @Peter: If there was a standard problem I would get a compilation error, instead the compiler fails. Also let me highlight that there is no error if I don't use the debug flag..

Comment: "_If there was a standard problem I would get a compilation error_" This isn't true at all. There's whole classifications of errors that simply fall under "no diagnostic required". The "no error if not in debug" part probably comes from stomp detection or other safe-guards in debug-only. Either way, nesting 20+ containers in any way is asking for trouble -- even from a maintenance and readability perspective

Comment: @jav - I didn't suggest it was a problem with the standard.  It's a problem in your code.   Non-normative content in the standard is advice or (in this case) recommendations, and doesn't mean any diagnostic is required.   Essentially, if you write code that exceeds such recommendation (as you have) then you can expect a greater likelihood of problems - like a compiler crashing.   There are many possible explanations for you seeing the problem in a debug build and not if you "don't use the debug flag".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 8+7+6 strings in that definition, right? So, I'd say what you have on your hands is a relation of arity 21. Why not try:

```
constexpr const std::size_t my_arity = 21;
std::unordered_set<std::array<std::string, my_arity>> oups;
```

instead?

Comment: Exactly a flavor of this is what I should have used. I need the map instead of unordered_set though. Now to accept an answer I guess I need to have also the answer of why the error is happening. That would be more useful to the community..

Comment: Well, I guess a map is created with storage for a few nodes on the heap. Let's say it's 4 nodes. Also Now, with every level you go in deeper, you multiple the amount of storage used on the deepest level by that factor. So, 4^21 = 2^42 which is a lot of memory!

Comment: @ einpoklum: Now we have to remember the error appears only when the debug flag is used. Without the flag the compilation goes very fast and with no problem.

Comment: Accepted as I used something similar to this. Hopefully some day we get the exact reason of why was the original code failing.